# How to break iterating over a list in FSharp?

Tags: loops, f#, break

I want to stop iterating over a List when the first item matches a condition.

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]
let list2 = [1; 2; 9]
list1 |> List.iter (fun item ->
        match List.contains item list2 with
        | false -> printfn " Not Present %A" item
        | true -> printfn "%A" item)
```

I want to only print the first item that is not present here that would be 3 in this case. How do I do that while writing code functionally ?

Comment: Do keep in mind that this algorithm scales poorly.  If the lists are going to be large you may want to adopt a different algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

The ultimate basis of iteration in the functional world is recursion: your function calculates something, and then calls itself for the next step. Or it decides to stop and then it *doesn't* call itself. Simple.

Your particular case fits very neatly in this paradigm:

```
let rec loop list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> () // no more list - just return
    | head::tail ->
        if List.contains head list2
            then loop tail // deciding to call myself
            else printfn " Not Present %A" head // deciding not to call myself

loop list1  // Kick off the process
```

---

But what about `iter`? Well, all those fancy functions from the `List` module - including `iter` - are built on top of the same recursive scheme. They too decide to either call themselves on every step or not. For some of them you can influence the decision via parameters, for others you can't.

It just so happens that for `iter` you cannot. `iter` will always call itself for the next step, so it will always iterate over the whole list. Nothing you can do about it.

But there are other functions for which you *can* influence the decision to recurse or not. There are many of them, but for your purposes, I think, `List.tryFind` would fit best. It takes another function as a parameter, which should return either `true` or `false`. If it returns `true`, `tryFind` will stop iterating and return the current element. Exactly what you need.

```
list1 |> List.tryFind (fun x -> 
  if List.contains x list2
    then false
    else printfn " Not Present %A"; true
)
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? You can do that by clicking the pale grey checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [F# Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/sequences) in which elements are evaluated in a lazy manner. In the sequence expression, use the good old `for` loop to find the required elements and `yield` them.

To "simulate" the "break iterating" you just use the built-in functions like `Seq.tryHead` or `Seq.take` or `Seq.truncate`.

As you can see, the nice thing about this approach is that it is easy to extend to find two or three first elements, or all elements, which match the requirement.

```
let notIn list x = list |> List.contains x |> not // just a helper function
seq { for x in list1 do
        if x |> notIn list2 then yield x }
|> Seq.tryHead // or Seq.take 2 or Seq.truncate 3
|> printfn "%A"
```

Sometimes, using the "imperative-like" approach such as `for` loop can make the code easier to understand (from my observation most of programmers have imperative background, including me). Notice that the code above is still functional.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tryPick here.
One advantage of this implementation is that the IO function (printfn) is kept separate from the algorithm.

```
let notPresent = 
    list1 
    |> List.tryPick 
        (fun item -> 
            if List.contains item list2 
                then None 
                else Some item) 

match notPresent with
    |   None -> ()
    |   Some x -> printfn " Not Present %A" x
```